# React Router 4 authentification and redirection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to implement an authentification system to my app with React Router.
But i'm having trouble to find a correct way to do this.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      logged : false
    }

  }

  isUserConnected(){
    // Contact server to know if user is connected or not
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
            <Route path="/privatePart" component={Application} /> 
            <Route path="/login" component={LoginRedirection} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch> 
        </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

**In the LoginRedirection component, there is a login form that make a POST to connect the user. But how this component can set logged to true in the App component ?**

Maybe I should learn redux ? It may be simplier to implement authentification with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux could be a solution, but you can do this with React and `react-router`.

Using `react-router`, you can use **the property `onEnter`**. For example, you can make the privatePart URL accessible only to logged users with something like:

```
  <Route path="/privatePart" component={Application} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
```

`requireAuth` should be a function that checks if the user has logged in or not. I think that using App's state isn't the best way to do this, since that information will be lost if the web is reloaded. You could store the login token or just a flag in the **`localStorage`** when the POST returns OK in the Login component. Then, redirect the user to `privatePart` and he will only be able to access it if `requireAuth` returns true (checking the `localStorage`). It could be something like:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("logged") === null) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

where username is the key you would add to the localStorage when the login is successful.

Comment: I think that onEnter prop is replaced with <Redirect /> object in router 4.
Tanks for your anwser, using localStorage seems to be a great idea !

Comment: By the way, if I use redux, the refresh and loose data problem will still be a thing ?

Comment: You are welcome :) And yes, with redux the data is also lost when you refresh but there are some solutions to this problem like [redux-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-storage) or [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist). I think that using localStorage is usually fine though.  At the end of the day, it depends highly on the full architecture of the system and the login process.

Comment: Really interesting libs ! I think I should wait a bit before learning Redux, but this could help me later. Thanks a lot for your help :)